# Cannot update Laravel Session variable?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session

I have an ongoing problem in Laravel. I am building "load more" system for comments with Laravel and Ajax, and using Session variable for counting and skipping already loaded rows. But for some reason my session variable wont persist, for unknown reason (trying whole the day to resolve this).. Ok here is some code:

```
 public function load_more() {

             $comments = Comments::whereid(Input::get('article_id'))->orderBy('id','DESC')->skip(Session::get('loaded')->take(12)->get();

             Session::set('loaded', Session::get('loaded')  +  12 ) ;

             return   \Response::json($comments);
     }
```

So as you can see i am trying to increment variable each call. But the variable stays the same all the time.. When I make another variable for example `Session::set('another', Session::get('loaded')  +  12 ) ;`
it actually get summed and i have sum in this variable.. but why it cannot update itself?

Comment: Have you tried `Session::set('loaded', Session::pull('loaded')  +  12 ) ;` It could be an issue where Laravel doesn't want to overwrite the already taken session key. `pull` should delete & return the value - which means you can reset the key to the new value.

Comment: just tried.. the same result

Comment: You are returning a json response. If you are viewing `Session('loaded')` in your view, you probably have to refresh the page to see the effect. Did you forget to do so? In the wildest of possible cases

Comment: I've just tried the code in your question on my local environment - it seems by adding `Session::save()` fixes your problem.

Comment: tried with Session::save() , still not updated. I am getting the '12' in the View as I am clicking on loadmore button. It should be 12,24,36.. Going crazy about this..

Comment: yes it's ajax, so is this a problem? Session variable wont update dynamicaly?

Comment: Why dont you save the session on the client side instead and use pagination at the backend. I guess that will save you alot of hustle.

Comment: not sure what you mean.. i just need to find the answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem in frontend with Jquery global counter which I am sending as an GET argument on every request, instead of using Session variables. Still don't know what's the problem with session, maybe some bug in my Laravel installation.

Answer (score 0):

If your have laravel 5.2 the probleme is you put your route into group web

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

            PUT YOUR ROUTE HERE

}
```